# laravel returns error 403 when trying to access an image or file in a new directory that was created while uploading the file

Tags: laravel, react-native, http-status-code-403, laravel-filesystem

laravel returns 403 forbidded when trying to access a file I uploaded to a new directory that was created while uploading the file

Please help what can I do?

Comment: Depends where the directory was that you created....

Comment: @Snapey thanks for your response, i linked the directory to a directory that is outside of the laravel app

Comment: Your web server can only serve images that are within the public area of the site (the document root and all the folders below it).  It cannot serve images from a folder elsewhere

Comment: I still don't understand that, it only worked after I changed ran laravel permission commands - to give permission to laravel's storage and bootstrap folder - but it gave me concern that, I'm I going to be running that same command everytime a user creates a directory for the user to be able to access the files in the directory

Comment: These should not be accessible.  Presumably you have `public' visible in your URLs which indicates a security issue

Comment: okay, please could you propose a solution for it?

Comment: Serve the public folder as the _document root_ and store the images in some folder off public

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try that, please how do I serve the public folder as the document root?

Comment: Depends on your web server (nginx or Apache usually)  Plenty to google, eg `set nginx document root`

Comment: okay, thanks, I will google it and try it